# How to convert this NSTimeInterval line from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

How to convert this into Objective-C ?

```swift
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: interval)
```

I tried this:

```objc
NSDate *date = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (interval)];
```

It generates an error of course.

Tells me: No known class method for selector timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:

Also here is some context:

```
 NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate alloc]init].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + [NSDate weekInSeconds].doubleValue;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (interval)];
    return [self isSameWeekAsDate:(date)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` is not a method implemented on the `NSDate` class.  When bridging from Objective-C to Swift, Swift does some renaming with initializers.

In order to initialize an `NSDate` object in Objective-C with a reference date, you must call either the class method `dateWith...` or the instance method `initWith...`:

```
NSDate * const date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval];
```

or...

```
NSDate * const date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval];
```

I've added the `const` here to make this more closely match the Swift code with the `let` declaration.